# Overscript distance

Tags: formatting

When I write:

```
Overscript[PQ, \[RightVector]],
```

the arrow is placed too close to the `P` and `Q`.
Is there a way to modify the default distance used by `Overscript`?

Comment: Quick fix is to select `PQ` or overscript and ALT+UpArrow/DownArrow.

Comment: @kuba ...also the best fix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see the problem of **close spacing** only for `OverVector`, not for the input with `Overscript` (where in your example I had to add quotation marks around the arrow symbol to avoid getting an error).

So I'm now assuming you're actually referring to the following issue:

```
OverVector[PQ]
```

[image: vec]

This could be remedied by adding an [`AdjustmentBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AdjustmentBox.html) around the arrow with the help of a formatting command like this:

```
OverVector /: MakeBoxes[OverVector[x_], _] := 
 OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], 
  AdjustmentBox["\[RightVector]", BoxBaselineShift -> -0.5]]

OverVector[PQ]
```

[image: vec2]

This enlarged spacing will work by default in `StandardForm` and `TraditionalForm` output.

**Edit**

For backward compatibility with *Mathematica* version 7, Mr. Wizard pointed out that it's good to add another option:

```
OverVector /: MakeBoxes[OverVector[x_], _] := 
 OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], 
  AdjustmentBox["\[RightVector]", BoxBaselineShift -> -0.5, 
   BoxMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0.5, 0}}]]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that seems to cover all versions and works fine. I also just checked that it works in version 9.